# Is there a blocking pop operation on Redis Sets?

Tags: redis

I have a bunch of workers that produce results (URIs) and they are put in a Redis Set to eliminate duplicates. Now I have another pool of workers that will pick work coming in (URIs). I would use BRPOP for this if the first "queue" was a List, but it's now a Set.

Is there anyway forward, except redesigning the flow (list -> check in set for duplicates -> new list)?

Comment: Redis has excellent documentation. If a command is not on http://redis.io/commands then it likely doesn't exist.

Comment: I think the only way is to redesign the flow. You can try [HyperLogLog](http://redis.io/commands/pfadd) instead of a set to trade duplicate detection accuracy for memory (if amount of used RAM is a concern, I mean).

Comment: Add it to the queue to be processed if it is not already in the set?

Comment: Can't you use SPOP? It removes and returns an element, but you just don't control which element. I don't see other option, not even a lua script with sscan because sscan is non-deterministic so you can't delete any key after running it.

Comment: @LiviuCostea: SPOP lacks the "blocking" semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redesign the flow and use the atomicity that Redis offers (via `MULTI` or `EVAL`) to ensure that your List and Set are kept consistent.